# Processing SOAP messages with Akka

Tags: http, scala, servlets, akka

I'm in the process of building a small tool for my employer, and attempting to implement it using Akka 2 + Scala.

One of the systems I'm interfacing with has a a SOAP api, which has an interesting implementation:

----Request-------

Client ----Request----> Server

Client <---Req Ack----- Server

----Response------

Client <---Response---- Server

Client ----Resp Ack---->Server

Keeping track of the requests is done via a task id sent by the req-ack.

My question is to the SO community and anyone who has experience with akka are the following:

- What would be an ideal way to handle http messages using akka for this particular scenario? I have seen examples with Akka-Mist, which looks like it's been discontinued in favor of play-mini, then there's akka-camel, which I can't seem to be able to find the library for as part of the akka 2.0.3 distribution, so I'm a little confused as to what approach I should take. Is there a recommended way to wrap a encapsulate a servlet's behavior inside an akka actor?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You're not specifying if the application is the client or the server.

Comment: The application is a client, however must also have an uri endpoint to receive responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is VERY open ended so I will make some assumptions about your requirements.

Request assumption:  There are a lot of requests being generated upon some event.

Create a router having actors that wrap the async-http-client (https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client).  Once the async-http-client completes a request it would send a message having the ID contained in the Req Ack to a coordination actor.  The coordination actor would aggregate the ID's.

The following is largely pseudocode but it's close enough to the real API that you should be able to figure out the missing pieces.

```
case class Request(url:String)
case class IDReceived(id:String)

case class RequestingActor extends Actor {

    override def receive = {
        case Request(url) => {
            //set up the async client and run the request
            //since it's async the client will not block and this actor can continue making generating more requests
        }
    }
}


class AsyncHttpClientResponseHandler(aggregationActor:ActorRef) extends SomeAsyncClientHandler {

    //Override the necessary Handler methods.

    override def onComplete = {
        aggregationActor ! IDReceived(//get the id from the response)
    }
}

class SomeEventHandlerClass { 

    val requestRouter = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[RequestingActor].withRouter(FromConfig(//maybe you've configured a round-robin router)), requestRouterName)

    def onEvent(url:String) {
        requestRouter ! Request(url)
    }

}

case class AggregationActor extends Actor {

    val idStorage = //some form of storage, maybe a Map if other information about the task ID needs to be stored as well.  Map(id -> other information)

    override def receive = {
        case IDReceived(id) => //add the ID to idStorage
    }
}
```

Response assumption: You need to do something with the data contained in the response and then mark the ID as complete.  The HTTP frontend only needs to deal with this one set of messages.

Instead of trying to find a framework with Akka integration just use a simple HTTP frontend that will send messages into the Akka network you've created.  I can't imagine any advantage gained by using play-mini and I think it would obscure some of the lines delineating work separation and control.  That's not always the case but given the lack of requirements in your question I have nothing else to base my opinion on.

```
case class ResponseHandlingActor extends Actor {

    val aggregationActor = actorSystem.actorFor(//the name of the aggregation router within the Actor System)

    override def receive = {
        case Response(data) => {
            //do something with the data.  If the data manipulation is blocking or long running it may warrant its own network of actors.
            aggregationActor ! ResponseReceived(//get the id from the response)
        }
    }
}

class ScalatraFrontEnd() extends ScalatraServlet {

    val responseRouter = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[RequestingActor].withRouter(FromConfig(//maybe you've configured a round-robin router)), requestRouterName)

    post("/response") {
        responseRouter ! Response(//data from the response)
    }

}
```

Creating a system similar to this gives you nice separation of concerns, makes it really easy to reason about where processing takes place and plenty of room for scaling the system or extending it.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!